# How to detect was EllipsisWord applied or not?

Tags: winforms, graphics, ellipsis

In winforms app I use `Graphics.DrawString(String, Font, Brush, RectangleF, StringFormat)` with `StringTrimming.EllipsisWord` for the last parameter. How can I know was the String ellipsed by the method or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't tell directly.  You'll have to measure first to see if it fits, Graphics.MeasureString().